# JavaScript .load does not show correct page results after .click

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code allows the user to click as button and reject a friend request. Even though multiple results are shown on a page, it functions correctly as it uses `wrapper.children('.decline').click(function() {` to target the correct result.

After this happens the following `$( "#containerFriends" ).load("friends.html #containerFriends" );` should refresh the page so that the latest results are displayed. However a completely blank page is shown, even when results should still exist. If I manually refresh the page, the correct results are shown.

I'm not sure what is wrong with the below and what is causing such an issue?

```
mainQuery.find({
            success: function(results) {
                var friends = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    friends.push({
                        imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                        username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                        userId: results[i].get('toUser').id,
                        status: results[i].get('status'),



                        // Saves the object so that it can be used below to change the status//
                        fetchedObject: results[i]


                    });


                }
                var select = document.getElementById("FriendsConnected");
                $.each(friends, function(i, v) {
                    var opt = v.username;
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    select.appendChild(el);
                })


                $('#containerFriends').empty();
                $('#containerFriendsConnected').empty();

                _.each(friends, function(item) {
                    var wrapper = $('<div class="portfolio-item-thumb one-third"></div>');
                    wrapper.append('<img class="responsive-image friendImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />' + '<br>');
                    wrapper.append('<div class="tag">' + item.username + '</div>');
                    wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="btn btn-danger mrs decline">' + 'Unfriend' + '</div>');

                    $('#containerFriends').append(wrapper);



                    //The following lets the user accept or decline a friend request by changing the status the status from Pending to Declined/////
                    wrapper.children('.decline').click(function() {
                        $(".decline").click(function() {
                            item.fetchedObject.set("status", "Rejected");
                            $( "#containerFriends" ).load("friends.html #containerFriends" );


                            item.fetchedObject.save(null, {
                                success: function(results) {
                                    console.log("REJECTED");

                                },
                                error: function(contact, error) {
                                    // The save failed.
                                    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                                }
                            });


                        });


                    });

                });

            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually resolved this by calling the function again, this then ensured the data was upto date and refreshed the page. I believe the issue was that `$('#containerFriends').append(wrapper);` did'nt contain the updated data after the user `.click`